# Firebase Cloud Functions: app/invalid-credential failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am new to Cloud Functions. I followed the docs, and the new initialization syntax for firebase-admin, but I am getting an auth error when running the function on the server and on a localhost.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}
```

I tried instantiating the sdk with a `serviceAccountKey`, same issue. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk

The function is being triggered on localhost and on the server, and error is being thrown once the call to the database is being made at `gettingUser()`

When running locally after building:

```
$ firebase experimental:functions:shell
firebase > const data = {some_article...}
firebase > addingNewArticle(data)
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > >  New article created articleId1

DEBUG: @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}
```

`/index.ts`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const addingNewArticle = functions.database
.ref('/articles/{articleId}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  const burgerId = context.params.burgerId

  const result = await gettingUser();
  console.log(`From onCreate ${result}`);


  console.log(`New article created ${articleId}`)

  const burgersVal = snapshot.val()
  const name = burgersVal.name
  const addedById = burgersVal.addedById

  console.log(`${name} was added by: ${addedById}`);
  console.log(`burgersVal: ${burgersVal}`);
  console.log(`snapshot: ${snapshot}`);


  return Promise.all([])
})


export async function gettingUser() {
    const result = await admin.database().ref(`users/fnkjasdfadsfna.d`).once('value');
    console.log(`Looging new user ${result.val()}`);
    return result.val()
}
```

Comment: Please post an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub with full steps that reproduce the problem, and be sure your CLI is fully up to date.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Also consider why you're not passing any parameters to Promise.all.  It's a function that takes an array of promises, but you're not even calling it.